# cover standardcontroller extension in test class

Tags: unit-test, controller, standardcontroller

```
public DiscoverOrg_ConflictResolver(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        LoadPage();
        // Research request start
        reportSubmited = '';
        reportNotSubmited = '';
        testing = false;
        // Research request Ends
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far and where the issue you are facing?

Comment: You don't need to cover (or test at all) the standard controller. That is Salesforce code. You only need to test your own. code.

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to create an instance of your controller extension and test it (here assuming `Contact` but use whatever type you are working with):

```
@IsTest
private class DiscoverOrg_ConflictResolverTest {

    @IsTest
    static void test() {

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Smith');
        insert c;

        DiscoverOrg_ConflictResolver controller = new DiscoverOrg_ConflictResolver(
                new ApexPages.StandardController(c)
                );

        // Add asserts for intitial state of controller
        // Add controller method/property calls and asserts
    }
}
```